# automatic convert 0 or empty string to NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

[in MySQL]
Is there any way to constraint any field to not be 0, and if I got 0 value convert it to NULL.
For example, two products can't have the same serial number, but product can be without serial number at all.
I'm using right now this:(for few fields)

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    sn DECIMAL(8,2),
    UNIQE (sn),
    ...........
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TRIGGER prod_zero1 BEFORE UPDATE ON products FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.sn=NULLIF(NEW.sn,0);
```

Is there any shorter\faster way how to do it ?
Other problem is that when I try to use this for few fields in the same table, I got massege:

```
CREATE TRIGGER prod_zero2 BEFORE UPDATE ON products FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.name=NULLIF(NEW.name,"");
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'
```

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest this kind of data validation/manipulation should be at a higher level in your app, i.e. the code that handles input and generates the SQL

Comment: BR, please don't ask multiple questions in one post, split them up in two questions instead.

Comment: regarding your first question, The trigger is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Agree, trigger is your best bet I think. Regarding qeustion 2; you only need 1 trigger to do all the checking..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use multiple triggers, use one trigger that takes care for all of the field

```
CREATE TRIGGER prod_zero2 BEFORE UPDATE ON products FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.sn=NULLIF(NEW.sn,0);
SET NEW.name=NULLIF(NEW.name,"");
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this:
 CREATE TRIGGER prod_zero BEFORE UPDATE ON products FOR EACH ROW
 SET  NEW.price=NULLIF(NEW.price,0),NEW.name=NULLIF(NEW.name,"");
it's even shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single trigger.

Here are the two columns from your example combined into one trigger. I just did an update triggers because that's what you had in your example, but you'll probably want another trigger to do the same thing for inserts, too.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_b_upd_products $$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_b_upd_products BEFORE UPDATE ON products FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.sn = 0)
  THEN
    SET NEW.sn=NULL;
  END IF;

  IF (NEW.name = '')
  THEN
    SET NEW.name=NULL;
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```